# Line disappear when camera move in three js

Tags: javascript, typescript, graph, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to render d3 force graph in three.js, I'm using standard Line and BoxGeometry with photo texture on it. On force graph update I call draw function, which is also called on in

```
controls.addEventListener('change', () => {this.redraw()});
```

but when I move camera, some lines disappear, when I'm closer, it seems worst, besides it does not look like there is any rule, even when I'm close to graph, it look like lines to disappear are chosen at random.

There line is

[image]

And this is if I move camera a little in angle

[image]

This is from one side of the graph:

[image]

And this is when from other:

[image]

[I tried to scale down units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185783/three-js-things-disappear-when-zooming-out)

[And also frustum = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855271/three-js-buffergeometry-disappears-after-moving-camera-to-close)

Whole code:

```
import {
    WebGLRenderer,
    Scene,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Texture,
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    SphereGeometry,
    Mesh,
    Geometry,
    Vector3,
    LineBasicMaterial,
    Line,
    LineSegments,
    BoxGeometry,
    TextureLoader
} from 'three';

import * as three from 'three';

import { ViewModel, Link, Node } from './Model';
import { event } from 'd3-selection';
import * as selection from 'd3-selection';
import { drag } from 'd3-drag';

// Old module syntax
declare function require(name:String);

let OrbitControls = require('./../../../node_modules/three-orbit-controls/index')(three);

interface IView {
    render():void;
}

class ViewNode {
    public vector:Vector3;
    public mesh:Mesh;
    public node:Node;
}

export class Full3DView implements IView {
    private canvas: Element;

    private renderer: WebGLRenderer;

    private scene: Scene;

    private lineMaterial: LineBasicMaterial;

    private camera: PerspectiveCamera;

    private controls: any;

    private nodes:ViewNode[] = [];

    private lines:Geometry[] = [];

    constructor(private model:ViewModel) {
        this.canvas = document.querySelector('#view3d2');
        this.model.onChange(() => {this.render()});
    }

    render(): void {
        this.buildScene();
        this.model.simulation.on('tick', () => this.redraw());
        this.model.linkForce.distance(40);
        this.model.collideForce.radius(30);
    }

    private buildScene() {
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );

        this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight );
        this.canvas.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

        this.controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
        this.controls.addEventListener('change', () => {this.redraw()});

        this.lineMaterial = new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xccff00, linewidth: 3});

        let vectorIndex:Map<String, Vector3> = new Map();
        let textureLoader = new TextureLoader();

        this.model.nodes.forEach((node:Node) => {
            this.buildNode(vectorIndex, textureLoader, node);
        });

        this.model.links.forEach((link:Link) => {
            this.buildEdge(vectorIndex, link);
        });

        this.camera.position.z = 5000;
    }

    private buildNode(vectorIndex:Map<String, Vector3>, textureLoader:TextureLoader, node:Node) {
        let material = new MeshBasicMaterial();
        let geometry = new BoxGeometry( 30, 30, 30);
        let mesh = new Mesh( geometry, material );

        mesh.lookAt(this.camera.position);

        this.scene.add( mesh );

        mesh.position.set(node.x, node.y, 0);

        mesh.rotation.x += 1;

        vectorIndex.set(node.index, mesh.position);

        this.nodes.push({
            vector: mesh.position,
            mesh: mesh,
            node: node
        });

        textureLoader.load('/data/images/' + node.id + '.jpg', (texture:Texture) => {
            material.map = texture;
            material.needsUpdate = true;
        });
    }

    private buildEdge(vectorIndex:Map<String, Vector3>, link:Link) {
        let geometry = new Geometry();

        geometry.vertices.push(
       vectorIndex.get(link.source.index).copy(vectorIndex.get(link.source.index).setZ(0)),
            vectorIndex.get(link.target.index).copy(vectorIndex.get(link.target.index).setZ(0))
        );

        geometry.computeLineDistances();

        this.lines.push(geometry);

        let line = new Line(geometry, this.lineMaterial);
        this.scene.add(line);
    }

    private redraw() {
        this.nodes.forEach((node:ViewNode) => {
            node.vector.setX(node.node.x * 10);
            node.vector.setY(node.node.y * 10);
            node.mesh.lookAt(this.camera.position);
            node.mesh.frustumCulled = false;
        });

        this.lines.forEach((line:Geometry) => {
            line.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        });

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get it working using `Line` object, but if I use `LineSegments` and push all pairs of vertices to one `Geometry`, it is working well.

So in function `buildScene` I use instead of

```
this.lineMaterial = new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xccff00, linewidth: 3});
```

lines

```
this.linesGeometry = new Geometry();
this.scene.add(new LineSegments(this.linesGeometry, new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xccff00, linewidth: 3})));
```

and then content of `buildEdge` is

```
this.linesGeometry.vertices.push(
    vectorIndex.get(link.source.index).copy(vectorIndex.get(link.source.index).setZ(0)),
    vectorIndex.get(link.target.index).copy(vectorIndex.get(link.target.index).setZ(0))
);
```

and in `redraw` function I just do

```
this.linesGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

instead of

```
this.lines.forEach((line:Geometry) => {
    line.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
});
```

Comment: (1) Rendering all the segments in a single draw call is clearly an improvement. (2) A possible explanation for your issue is that when you update the vertices of a geometry, you should call `geometry.computeBoundingSphere()`. The renderer calls it for you on the first render call, but after that, if you modify vertices, the bounding sphere is no longer correct, and you need to update it. Alternatively, you can set `mesh.frustumCulled = false`;

Answer (score 7):

The actual answer I was looking for is in the comment above from [WestLangley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461008/westlangley).

> A possible explanation for your issue is that when you update the vertices of a geometry, you should call `geometry.computeBoundingSphere()`. The renderer calls it for you on the first render call, but after that, if you modify vertices, the bounding sphere is no longer correct, and you need to update it. Alternatively, you can set `mesh.frustumCulled = false`;

Comment: I had the same problem, and this was the cause (and solution)!

Comment: I think, this should be accepted answer. It work for me. I have these problem in my dynamic line implementation. And this happen me only in one special case. Thanks for help.